# Spring batch: FieldSetMapper should set field to null instead of empty

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch to read pipe (| delimited) separated file which have have **7 field**. I created a class called MyLineMapper that extends spring's FieldSetMapper. This class maps field values provided in file to my object (XYZ type). Now the problem is that fieldSet object that i get inside class extending FieldSetMapper contain empty value for field that are not present in delimited values.

**For example:** 
Suppose that the delimited file format is as follows: **|ID|Country|City|Pin|**
Suppose i provide following line in file: **|1|India|**
As you can see the above line does not contain information for City and Pin. Therefore, I expect FieldSet object should contain Null value for these two fiels (City and Pin) instead of empty string. I don't want empty value as Null will help me to know if that field was actually present in file or not.

How can I achieve this ? Do I need to extend DelimitedLineTokenizer which I am using for tokenizing ? Or this is a simple way to do this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

From FieldSetMapper javadoc

> To customize the way that FieldSet values are converted to the desired
>   type for injecting into the prototype there are several choices. You
>   can inject PropertyEditor instances directly through the customEditors
>   property, or you can override the createBinder(Object) and
>   initBinder(DataBinder) methods, or you can provide a custom FieldSet
>   implementation.

Depending on type of your target bean conversion is done using default Spring convention. If you need other type of logic write your own.